# Find location of bash command binary file

Tags: bash

I have a command `letsencrypt` which I use in the terminal.

I tried to find the binary via `grep -R "letsencrypt" /`. Not a good idea, some sort of loop was invoked.

Is there a simple command to see what the command `letsencrypt` actually invokes for binary?

Comment: Maybe worth noting that executables (ie whatever is found in the PATH by running a command like `letsencrypt` or found by `which letsencrypt`) may be scripts (or symlinks, or symlinks to scripts) too, not necessarily binary files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `which letsencrypt` or `type letsencrypt`.

Answer (score 2):

You can locate programs, scripts and symbolic links, that are in `$PATH` (and executed without the total or relative path) with the following command line

```
which program-name   # general
which letsencrypt    # your example
```

If `letsencrypt` is a script, you can view it with a text viewer, for example `less` or your favorite editor.

```
less /path-found-by-which/letsencrypt
```